# add labels to multiple GCP compute instances at the same time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

can I update multiple GCP instances using `gcloud` at the same time? I am looking to add label to all my instances and I don't see a way to do it for multiple instances at the time like AWS has with its `awscli`.

i can do

```
gcloud compute instances update test-instance --update-labels test=foo
```

would want something like

```
gcloud compute instances update test-instance1 test-instance2 --update-labels test=foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, no there isn't. However it's straightforward to use a shell (e.g. bash) to enumerate the list of instances and run the command for each:

```sh
for INSTANCE in "test-instance1" "test-instance2"
do
  gcloud compute instances update ${INSTANCE} --update-labels ...
done
```

The command appears to **not** support the `--async` flag so you will need to run these commands sequentially, unless you throw them into the background.

This approach is less elegant than being able to issue one command that effects multiple updates (service-side) but I suspect it's a relatively infrequent requirement and, for smaller number of instances, the existing command is probably sufficient.

You may combine the update with e.g. an instances list:

```sh
for INSTANCE in $(gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name)")
...
```

You can submit a feature request to Google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=1163129

Comment: ended up doing that, was hoping that Im missing some pre-made solution, they already have UI multi-select => add tags, was sure there was an API call for that sort of thing

Comment: It's a reasonable request and you should consider submitting a FR to Google's Issue Tracker.